# How can I change the way NSButtonCell objects highlight when clicked?

Tags: cocoa

I am using several NSButtonCell objects in an NSTableView. They are simple square buttons with custom images on them.

These buttons draw properly when they are not highlighted: all that is visible is the image, and the rest of the button rectangle is transparent. However, when I click on them, the entire button rectangle is highlighted, inverting the background in the parts that were transparent.

I would prefer to see the image drawn inverted, and the transparent parts remain transparent. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting your cell's `highlightsBy` property to `NSContentsCellMask`. I think you'll have to do this in code (probably in `awakeFromNib`); I don't see a way to do it in IB alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Interface Builder too. I use "`Square Button`" so the button alters between two images (so the image is not inverted at all).

Your buttons behaviour is probably set to "`Momentary Light`" or "`Momentary Push In`".

Set the `Behaviour` to "`Momentary Change`", and it should work.